# python extract vowels from words

Tags: python, mapreduce

I am reading in a string of words and trying to retrieve all the vowels in them but not having much success. so if I have this: ***Hello this is a test this is***. I want to return something like this:

### :|eo| 1 :|

### :|i | 1 :|

### :|i | 1 :|

### :|a | 1 :|

### :|i | 1 :|

### :|i | 1 :|

Here is the latest version of my code which just prints the word, I know I need to loop through each word but can't figure out how without it turning into an endless loop.

```
import sys
import re
import string

line = sys.stdin.readline()
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
line = line.lower()
line = line.replace(',', ' ').replace(';',' ').replace('”','').replace('?', .').replace('!','.')
word = line.split()

print(word)
line = sys.stdin.readline()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this

```
string = "hello this is a test this is"
vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

for word in string.split(" "):
    new_word = ""
    for char in word:
        new_word = new_word + char if char in vowels else new_word
    print(f"|: {new_word} :|")
```

**output**

```
|: eo :|
|: i :|
|: i :|
|: a :|
|: e :|
|: i :|
|: i :|
```

Answer (score 5):

```
sentence = line.split()
for word in sentence:
    vowel_list = [char for char in word if char in vowels]
```

You now have a list of only the vowels in the given word.  Combine and format as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another answer that builds on yours:

```
line = sys.stdin.readline()
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
line = line.lower()
line = line.replace(',', ' ').replace(';',' ').replace('”','').replace('?', '.').replace('!','.')
lst = line.split()

for idx, word in enumerate(lst):
    new_word = ''
    for letter in word:
        if letter in vowels:
            new_word += letter
            lst[idx] = new_word
print(lst)
#['eo', 'i', 'i', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'i']
```